# Note or book on Examples of regular, Gorenstein, Cohen Macaulay, ... rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, gorenstein, cohen-macaulay

I need a good **note** or **book** with plenty of examples in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry which surveyed being *regular, Gorenstein, Cohen Macaulay, ...*.
Can you help?
 thanks.

Comment: Commutative ring theory by H. Matsumura, for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. Thanks. But I mean solved *examples* not exercises.

Comment: Isn't Bruns and Herzog the standard reference for Cohen-Macaulay rings?